# UTF8 table - MySQL dump and import into UTF8mb4

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump, collation

MariaDB 10.4 database is UTF8_unicode_ci collation.

I need to export a table that will be imported into a UTF8mb4_unicode_ci database.

When dumping, if I run:

```
mysqldump -u -p --default-character-set=utf8mb4 database tablename > tablename.utfmb4.sql
```

Will this export the table in UTF8mb4 ready for me to import into the new database?

Comment: Utf8 is only a generic **character set**: the collation is vital and should be added as well

Comment: You are correct, apologies.

utf8_unicode_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_ci